# Unpivot Multiple Columns in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot, unpivot

I have a requirement to unpivot a table similar to the table below:

```
create TABLE dummy_x
(
    EMP_NAME            VARCHAR2(100)    
,   EMP_NUMBER          VARCHAR2(100)
,   PAYROLL_NAME        VARCHAR2(100)
,   PAYROLL_ID          NUMBER
,   JOB_TITLE           VARCHAR2(100)
,   JOB_TITLE_ID        NUMBER
,   LOCATION            VARCHAR2(100)
,   LOCATION_ID         NUMBER
,   NEW_PAYROLL_NAME    VARCHAR2(100)
,   NEW_PAYROLL_ID      NUMBER
,   NEW_JOB_TITLE       VARCHAR2(100)
,   NEW_JOB_TITLE_ID    NUMBER
,   NEW_LOCATION        VARCHAR2(100)
,   NEW_LOCATION_ID     NUMBER    
);

INSERT INTO dummy_x (EMP_NAME, EMP_NUMBER, PAYROLL_NAME, PAYROLL_ID, JOB_TITLE, JOB_TITLE_ID, LOCATION, LOCATION_ID, NEW_PAYROLL_NAME, NEW_PAYROLL_ID, NEW_JOB_TITLE, NEW_JOB_TITLE_ID, NEW_LOCATION, NEW_LOCATION_ID)
VALUES  ('MISIP', '111X', 'PAY1', 1, 'DEVELOPER', 2, 'PHIL', 3, 'PAYPHIL', 11, 'PHIL DEV', 22, 'MANILA PH', 33);

INSERT INTO dummy_x (EMP_NAME, EMP_NUMBER, PAYROLL_NAME, PAYROLL_ID, JOB_TITLE, JOB_TITLE_ID, LOCATION, LOCATION_ID, NEW_PAYROLL_NAME, NEW_PAYROLL_ID, NEW_JOB_TITLE, NEW_JOB_TITLE_ID, NEW_LOCATION, NEW_LOCATION_ID)
VALUES  ('FHONS', '111Y', 'PAY2', 2, 'SUPPORT', 3, 'HONDURAS', 4, 'PAYHON', 55, 'HON SUP', 66, 'SP SULA HON', 77);
```

I need the format to be something like below:

```
EMP_NAME    EMP_NUMBER      DETAILS         CURRENT_VALUE   NEW_VALUE
---------   ------------    --------------  --------------  ----------
MISIP       111X            PAYROLL_NAME    PAY1            PAYPHIL
                            PAYROLL_ID      1               11
                            JOB_TITLE       DEVELOPER       PHIL DEV
                            JOB_TITLE_ID    2               22
                            LOCATION        PHIL            MANILA PH    
                            LOCATION_ID     3               33           
FHONS       111Y            PAYROLL_NAME    PAY2            PAYHON
                            PAYROLL_ID      2               55
                            JOB_TITLE       SUPPORT         HON SUP
                            JOB_TITLE_ID    3               66
                            LOCATION        HONDURAS        SP SULA HON
                            LOCATION_ID     4               77
```

This is what i've done so far:

```
SELECT  EMP_NAME                
    ,   EMP_NUMBER          
    ,   Details
    ,   current_value
FROM    (SELECT EMP_NAME                
            ,   EMP_NUMBER          
            ,   PAYROLL_NAME        
            ,   cast(PAYROLL_ID as varchar2(100)) PAYROLL_ID
            ,   JOB_TITLE           
            ,   cast(JOB_TITLE_ID as varchar2(100)) JOB_TITLE_ID
            ,   LOCATION            
            ,   cast(LOCATION_ID as varchar2(100)) LOCATION_ID
            ,   NEW_PAYROLL_NAME    
            ,   cast(NEW_PAYROLL_ID as varchar2(100)) NEW_PAYROLL_ID
            ,   NEW_JOB_TITLE       
            ,   cast(NEW_JOB_TITLE_ID as varchar2(100)) NEW_JOB_TITLE_ID
            ,   NEW_LOCATION        
            ,   cast(NEW_LOCATION_ID as varchar2(100)) NEW_LOCATION_ID
        FROM    dummy_x)     
unpivot (current_value for Details in (PAYROLL_NAME        
                                   ,   PAYROLL_ID  
                                   ,   JOB_TITLE   
                                   ,   JOB_TITLE_ID
                                   ,   LOCATION    
                                   ,   LOCATION_ID));
```

**QUERY OUTPUT**

```
EMP_NAME    EMP_NUMBER      DETAILS         CURRENT_VALUE   NEW_VALUE
---------   ------------    --------------  --------------  ----------                                   
MISIP       111X            PAYROLL_NAME    PAY1
MISIP       111X            PAYROLL_ID      1
MISIP       111X            JOB_TITLE       DEVELOPER
MISIP       111X            JOB_TITLE_ID    2
MISIP       111X            LOCATION        PHIL
MISIP       111X            LOCATION_ID     3
FHONS       111Y            PAYROLL_NAME    PAY2
FHONS       111Y            PAYROLL_ID      2
FHONS       111Y            JOB_TITLE       SUPPORT
FHONS       111Y            JOB_TITLE_ID    3
FHONS       111Y            LOCATION        HONDURAS
FHONS       111Y            LOCATION_ID     4
```

How can i add the "New Value" Column data to this script and would it be possible to remove the duplicate data from the EMP_NAME and EMP_NUMBER columns?

Comment: Use your query output in your application code to the necessary modifications. SQL is not the suitable tool to do this kind of manipulation.

Comment: @GurV, not sure how i can proceed, i'm designing an application using OAF. any chance even for the "New Value" column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do the cell merging in your application code.

For new_value, try this:

```
SELECT  EMP_NAME                
    ,   EMP_NUMBER          
    ,   Details
    ,   current_value
    ,   new_value
FROM    (SELECT EMP_NAME                
            ,   EMP_NUMBER          
            ,   PAYROLL_NAME        
            ,   cast(PAYROLL_ID as varchar2(100)) PAYROLL_ID
            ,   JOB_TITLE           
            ,   cast(JOB_TITLE_ID as varchar2(100)) JOB_TITLE_ID
            ,   LOCATION            
            ,   cast(LOCATION_ID as varchar2(100)) LOCATION_ID
            ,   NEW_PAYROLL_NAME    
            ,   cast(NEW_PAYROLL_ID as varchar2(100)) NEW_PAYROLL_ID
            ,   NEW_JOB_TITLE       
            ,   cast(NEW_JOB_TITLE_ID as varchar2(100)) NEW_JOB_TITLE_ID
            ,   NEW_LOCATION        
            ,   cast(NEW_LOCATION_ID as varchar2(100)) NEW_LOCATION_ID
        FROM    dummy_x)     
unpivot ((current_value, new_value) for Details in (
                                       (PAYROLL_NAME, NEW_PAYROLL_NAME) as 'PAYROLL_NAME'
                                   ,   (PAYROLL_ID  , NEW_PAYROLL_ID ) as 'PAYROLL_ID'
                                   ,   (JOB_TITLE   , NEW_JOB_TITLE  ) as 'JOB_TITLE'
                                   ,   (JOB_TITLE_ID, NEW_JOB_TITLE_ID) as 'JOB_TITLE_ID'
                                   ,   (LOCATION    , NEW_LOCATION    ) as 'LOCATION'
                                   ,   (LOCATION_ID , NEW_LOCATION_ID) as 'LOCATION_ID'
                                   )
        );
```

Answer (score 3):

To get both columns is much easier than you may think:  `unpivot ( (current_value, new_value) for details in...)` Of course, the "details" should also be given in pairs, each enclosed in `( ... , ... )`. For example: `for ((payroll_name, new_payroll_name) as 'PAYROLL NAME', .... )`

The second requirement doesn't make sense. Which row should keep the EMP_NAME and the EMP_NUMBER, and which should show NULL? What if the row you "think" should get the values doesn't actually exist, or must be deleted in further processing? THAT is something you should do in your front-end application (for example in SQL*Plus, where what you want is easy to do).